# PDF with print module and wkhtmltopdf - how to install?

Tags: installation

I try to generate pdf with the print module and have tried it with the PDF generators MPDF and DOMPDF. Unfortunately, the results are of no use, which is why I want to try wkhtmltopdf. I read good things about it.

Unfortunately, the installation guide is outdated. For instance, I read that you don't need a x server anymore since 3 years.

*What I've done so far:*

- I have downloaded the latest version for Windows.
- As described in the instructions I put the executable in the directory sites / all / libraries.
- After I renamed the cryptic file names wkhtmltox-0.12.1.2_msvc2013-win32.exe in wkhtmltopdf, it was recognized in the print module settings.
- When I try to generate a PDF on my local installation, a confirmation dialog appears where I have to give permission and then I have to install the executable. After installation a error message occurs (the problem is known, so I will not thematize it further).

My first problem is that I do not know how the .exe needs to be used properly. Whenever I want to generate a PDF, I have to install the program (via "Allow" - "Terms of Conditions" agree and then "Install below C: // Program Files / Files") to continue. There is something wrong. Does anyone of you see the mistake in my procedure?

Or can someone give me an advise how to make wkhtmltopdf work with the print module on a localhost (WIN7 and XAMPP), please?

Answer (score 1):

> - I have downloaded the latest version for Windows.
> - As described in the instructions I put the executable in the directory sites / all / libraries.
> - After I renamed the cryptic file names wkhtmltox-0.12.1.2_msvc2013-win32.exe in wkhtmltopdf, it was recognized in the print module settings.

The executable you've downloaded is the installer, not the wkhtmltopdf executable. You need to **install** it to the `sites/all/libraries`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PHP WK HTML to PDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/phpwkhtmltopdf) module

> This module is a Drupal Library implementation for the PHPWkHtmlToPdf wrapper and as a result is extremely small because it uses WkHtmlToPdf to do the heavy work.